# One theme for all multiple store of one website and no subdomain

Tags: magento-1.8, theme, multistore

I am developing store having different multiple stores , i'm not using any subdomain for multiple website.

I have created main website and linked three stores , i want to use same theme but after switching to another store or language theme layout changed.

Answer (score 1):

The following steps you should take are:

1. Log in to the Magento admin and go to System -> Configuration.
2. In the configuration menu on the left side click on "Design" under the General section.
3. Here is where you want to make sure all of your setting are the default "fall back" configurations you want. If you look in the top left corner at "Current Configuration Scope" you should see "Default Config"
4. Once you have set up your defaults, you can change your "Current Configuration Scope" to the next store view you want to update. Make sure the package is the correct top level name of you directory under "frontend" in your code.  The themes section would contain the name of the sub directory of the package you are referring to.
5. Save Config after each update
6. Make sure you have cleared your cache.  The default cache is under System -> Cache Management.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in you backend, you can choose in the upper left the storeview or website.

When you choose your theme, make sure, that this setting is set to `default`.

Then check *ALL* other settings and make sure, that all other theme settings have a checkbox at `use default`.